# Is it possible to use a release snapshot variable in a new release?

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopus

I have an old Octopus release, unfortunately some of the variables from the snapshot variables taken at the time it was created are not longer in the variable configuration section or it has different values and I want to use that same configuration in a new release I just created.  is it possible to take the snapshot variable from the old release and use it into my new release? or a way to restore the missing variables in variables section from that old release snapshot variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, it is not possible. You could clone the project and update the variables manually from the snapshot and create the N+1 release with this. A little tedious, but should work.

Ref: https://help.octopus.com/t/create-release-with-specific-snapshots/19410/2